# nested route in nextjs group routing

Tags: reactjs, web, next.js, routes, nested

I have folders like this :
[image]

and I want to have /vendor/addProduct route but neither creating with folder nor file works.(it renders the content in vendor page.jsx not addProduct page.jsx)
I would appreciate your help

Comment: The folder structure is correct. 
I've tested your folder structure in my next.js 14 project, it worked well.
Could you check your render function in page.jsx?